# помогите решить задачу!!! тема частые сценарии

Tags: python

Количество чисел
На вход программе подаются два целых числа aa и bb (a \le b)(a≤b). Напишите программу, которая подсчитывает количество чисел в диапазоне от aa до bb включительно, куб которых оканчивается на 44 или 99.

Формат входных данных
На вход программе подаются два целых числа aa и bb (a \le b)(a≤b).

Формат выходных данных
Программа должна вывести одно целое число в соответствии с условием программы.

Примечание. Куб числа aa – это его третья степень a^3a
3
.

Sample Input 1:

1
10
Sample Output 1:

2
Sample Input 2:

1
100
Sample Output 2:

20
Sample Input 3:

10
1786
Sample Output 3:

355

Comment: помочь и решить за вас - разные вещи. ваш код где?

Comment: a,b=map(int,input().split())
print(sum(i%100 in (14,64,99) for i in range(a, b+1)))

Answer (score 1):

1. перебираете все числа от `left` до `right`
2. возводите каждое число в куб
3. определяете остаток куба от деления на 100 - это как раз последние 2 цифры и будут, например `12345 % 100 = 45`
4. добавляете в список только те числа, остатки от деления кубов на 100 которых удовлетворяют вашим критериям

в общем задача в 1 строчку если быть уж откровенным